# Iterate over an enum with typescript and assign to an enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I am attempting to iterate over all the values in an enum, and assign each value to a new enum. This is what I came up with....

```
enum Color {
    Red, Green
}

enum Suit { 
    Diamonds, 
    Hearts, 
    Clubs, 
    Spades 
}

class Deck 
{
    cards: Card[];

    public fillDeck() {
        for (let suit in Suit) {
            var mySuit: Suit = Suit[suit];
            var myValue = 'Green';
            var color : Color = Color[myValue];
        }
    }
}
```

The part `var mySuit: Suit = Suit[suit];` doesn't compile, and returns the error  `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Suit'`.

If I hover over `suit` in the for loop, it shows me `let suit: string`. `var color : Color = Color[myValue];` also compiles without error. What am I doing wrong here as both examples with Suit and Color look identical to me.

I'm on TypeScript version 2.9.2 and this is the contents of my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to iterate over all the values in an enum, whilst maintaining the enum type for each iteration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either use this hack:

```
const mySuit: Suit = Suit[suit] as any as Suit;
```

or change `Suit` enum to string enum and use it like this:

```
enum Suit { 
    Diamonds = "Diamonds", 
    Hearts = "Hearts", 
    Clubs = "Clubs", 
    Spades = "Spades",
}

for (let suit in Suit) {
    const mySuit: Suit = Suit[suit] as Suit;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

For string enum, if the `strict` flag is on, we will get `type string can't be used to index type 'typeof Suit'`. 
So we have to something like:

```
for (const suit in Suit) {
    const mySuit: Suit = Suit[suit as keyof typeof Suit];
}
```

If you just need the `string` value of it, then use `suit` directly is fine.